# How to extract the unique values from a separate ranges and concatenate to the adjacent column (offset (,-1) on the same range?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I need to extract the unique values from a separate ranges and concatenate to the adjacent column (offset (,-1) on the same range.
As you see on the below picture, I sort my dataset by column_A ,so all duplicate values on column_A will be together. 
I need to put the duplicate values on column_A with the respective cells on the same rows into a variable Range e.g `rng1 = [A2:C4]`, 
Then extract unique values found on rng1.columns(3) and concatenate to each cell on rng1.columns(2) ,range(“B2:B4”) 
By the same **rng2** will be = `[A5:C7]` and so on.
**The problem** is I do not know how when ID values is duplicates to put them and it’s adjacent cells on the same rows into a variable range and process it !
At end column C will be be deleted.
In advance, great thanks for your learning support.
[image]

```
Sub Extract_unique_values_and_combine_in_adjacent_cells()
 
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
 
   Dim arr: arr = rng.Value2
    Dim i As Long
     For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
 
   On Error Resume Next 'skip error if i= 1
      If arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1) Or _
         arr(i, 1) = arr(i - 1, 1) Then
        arr(i, 2) = arr(i, 2) & vbLf & unique(ws.Range("C2:C4").Value2) 'I need (crg) to be dynamic
      End If
   On Error GoTo 0
 
    Next i
 
   rng.Value = arr
 
End Sub
 
Function unique(crg)
 
   Dim cel, a
     With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
       For Each cel In crg
         a = .Item(cel)
       Next
     unique = Join(.Keys, vbLf)
    End With
 
End Function
```

Comment: Does it need to be VBA?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook ,sure to be VBA

Comment: Shame, was going to add that this formula will give you the Data_B column:  `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,B2,UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7=A2)))`

Comment: So, if "C3" will be "Text3", the return for first category (44) should be "Word1, Text1, Text3, Text2" separated by `vbLf`. From your (new) question I can understand that the **strings in column B:B should be unique per category** and they should be placed **on top of the strigs collected from B:C**. And from C:C, **only unique strings must be concatenated in the returned string**. Should this understanding be a correct one? If yes, I can rapidly prepare an answer. One able to process the range even if categories (44, 55 etc.) are not consecutive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary and arrays to keep, process and return the necessary strings. It will process all categories (unique in A:A) being in any order:

```
Sub CombineRanges()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrDict, dict As Object
   Dim arrDB, arrDC, mtch, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value2
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3)) 'place the strings from columns B and C
        Else
            arrDict = dict(arr(i, 1))                       'extract the array from dict items (it cnnot be modified inside the item)
            arrDict(0) = arrDict(0) & "|" & arr(i, 2)       'place in the array first element the strings collected from B:B
            arrDC = Split(arrDict(1), vbLf)                 'try splitting the second array element (string(s) from C:C)
            If UBound(arrDC) = 0 Then                       'if only one element:
                If arrDC(0) <> arr(i, 3) Then arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & vbLf & arr(i, 3) 'add to it the value from C:C, separated by vbLf
            Else
                mtch = Application.match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0) 'check unicity of the string from C:C
                If IsError(mtch) Then                         'only if not existing:
                    arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & vbLf & arr(i, 3)'add it to the string to be used in the next step
                End If
            End If
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrDict                         'put back the array in the dictionary item
        End If
   Next i

   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2): k = 1              'redim the final array and initialize k (used to fill the array)
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1                                'iterate between the dictionary keys/items:
        arrDict = dict.Items()(i)                             'place the item array in an array
        arrDB = Split(arrDict(0), "|")                        'obtain an array of B:B strins from the item first array element
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrDB)   'how many unique keys exists!
                arrFin(k, 1) = dict.Keys()(i)                 'place the dictionry key per each iteration
                arrFin(k, 2) = arrDB(j) & vbLf & arrDict(1)   'build the string of the second column
                k = k + 1
        Next j
   Next i
   'drop the processed result near the existing range (for easy visual comparison):
   sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

The above code assumes what I wrote in my comment placed some time before and you din not confirm/infirm...

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version. It will return only a column keeping the concatenated B:C columns value and skips the empty values in C:C, if the case. It will return in D:D, too. After testing, if it does what you need, just change "D" with "B" in the last code line:

```
Sub CombineRangesOneColumn()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrDict, dict As Object
   Dim arrDB, arrDC, mtch, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value2
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3)) 'place the strings from columns B and C
        Else
            arrDict = dict(arr(i, 1))                                   'extract the array from dict items (it cnnot be modified inside the item)
            arrDict(0) = arrDict(0) & "|" & arr(i, 2)        'place in the array first element the strings collected from B:B
            arrDC = Split(arrDict(1), vbLf)                      'try splitting the second array element (string(s) from C:C)
            If UBound(arrDC) = 0 Then                           'if only one element:
                If arrDC(0) <> arr(i, 3) Then arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & IIf(arr(i, 3) = "", "", vbLf & arr(i, 3)) 'add to it the value from C:C, separated by vbLf
            Else
                mtch = Application.match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0) 'check unicity of the string from C:C
                If IsError(mtch) Then                                          'only if not existing:
                    arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & IIf(arr(i, 3) = "", "", vbLf & arr(i, 3))       'add it to the string to be used in the next step
                End If
            End If
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrDict                                             'put back the array in the dictionary item
        End If
   Next i

   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1): k = 1            'redim the final array and initialize k (used to fill the array)
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1                                                'iterate between the dictionary keys/items:
        arrDict = dict.Items()(i)                                               'place the item array in an array
        arrDB = Split(arrDict(0), "|")                                      'obtain an array of B:B strins from the item first array element
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrDB)   'how many unique keys exists!                     'place the dictionry key per each iteration
                arrFin(k, 1) = arrDB(j) & vbLf & arrDict(1)       'build the string of the second column
                k = k + 1
        Next j
   Next i
   'drop the processed result near the existing range (for easy visual comparison):
   sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: The processed result is very good. Please, can you modify your code to drop the result on `column B` itself .
Also there is a little issue if there are a **blank cells** on column C, this leads subsequently to blanks on `arrFin`,
I know this issue can be handled later on column B, But I think it is better to be handled early with arrFin.

Comment: @Leedo For the first requirement, you should just change "D2" with "A2". If you want it a little more efficient, redim `ArrFin` to have a single column and not place `arr(i, 1)` anywhere. And, of course, drop the result in "B2". About the second one, I tried requiring a larger range containing more possible cases and you did not do it in the new question, neither. So, I answered your question as it has been formulated. You can easily adapt the code to not concatenate if `arr(i, 3) = ""`. It is easy to understand where to modify, since I comment all relevant code lines, I think.

Comment: Works perfectly and excellent answer . also I wish to tell you that I did not intend to ignore your inquiries yesterday.
I appreciate your genius codes.

Comment: @Leedo It is not a matter of ignoring a suggestion/requirement. It is a matter of placing clear questions. In the past, if a question looked challenging I used to design an answer according to my understanding against the way it was formulated. Sometimes my assumptions were correct, in other cases they were far away of the OP need. In such cases I wasted my time **not** because the OP, **because of me**, because I tried answering not clear questions. In my opinion, our job here is to make people also learning **how to ask a question**. How else to make them describing as accurate as possible?

Comment: For the first requirement, I did **redim ArrFin** to have a single column but I do not understand why not place `arr(i, 1`) anywhere on the code (I did not remove `arr(i, 1)` and works without issue).
For the second requirement, I think you mean  `if arr(i, 3) <> ""` instead of  if arr(i, 3) = "", anyhow I did not know where to put this condition.
If you have no will to complete your help, I have no problem to post a new question.

Comment: After testing your edited code, issue of blank cells is now fixed correctly .
**Note:** you mentioned that `One able to process the range even if categories (44, 55 etc.) are not consecutive` ,
I tried with that case and found that some output are wrong (either with initial answer and the edited one),
This is not a big issue with me because I will sort my dataset by column_A ,so all duplicate values on column_A will be together. https://easyupload.io/d38lf2

Comment: The code worked as I said **only in its first version**, when returned the whole range in a separate area. Of cource, returning in consecutive rows and impossible to match the same initial rows.

Comment: First ,I am sorry and **kindly accept my apology** (I was hurry to mention all works).
After I used your codes on my work real environment , I faced a new issue.
Supposing on my provided pictures on question that all cells on `Range(“C2:C4”)`  have no value **empty** ,
then I got **Run-time error '13':Type mismatch** on that line `mtch = Application.Match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0)  'check unicity of the string from C:C`
after I debugged I found ` i=2`

Comment: @Leedo I replied  from my mobile phone and I did not see your attachment. Your sent workbook only proves that the code works **as it should**, in terms of no consecutive categories. The return must be interpreted **only related to returned categories which are consecutive**.  Then, I cannot understand your last comment. Do you play with theoretical possibilities? The code has NOT been designed to deal with empty strings in C:C and I only adapted supposing that such empty cells appear only by mistake. I told you that I do not like wasting my time. So, can you accurately describe the used data?

Comment: @Leedo Please, mainly clarify this part: **Range(“C2:C4”) have no value empty**. Is it what you wanted saying? Or **ALL** values are empty? The workbook you sent **has no value empty in C:C**...

Comment: Yes, I **clarify this part**: IF `Range(“C2:C4”)` have no value ,then I got Run-time error '13':Type mismatch on that line `mtch = Application.Match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0)` 'check unicity of the string from C:C after I debugged I found `i=2`

Comment: @Leedo **have no value empty"" is exactly opposite to **have no value**. If your real case can have an empty cell **in the first category occurrence** it may behave as you say... This problem starts, as I said, from the fact that the code has not been designed to handle such empty cells.

Comment: regarding **Run-time error '13':Type mismatch** , I put `On Error Resume Next` before that line and the error has been fixed ,may be it is not the optimal fix , but it solved the issue.

Comment: Also, `Great thanks` for your comments found on the code itself , It is very helpful for me and anyone looking for a similar  answer

Comment: Ok , I will post a new question to handle the new requirements.

Comment: @Leedo I do not think `On Error Resume Next` is a solution. Not because is not elegant. It will not allow building the necessary string if some others will exist in the next occurrence of the same category...

Comment: I do not know why you deleted your recent answer. You always ask our feedback.(With no offence) But I did not **confirm or said** on column `B:B` will not have a blank cells,
even my provided picture and sample workbook shows empty cell on column B:B. anyhow as you like.

Comment: Yes, I like feedback and I explained in my last comment what happened, what I intend to do and suggested to mark as accepted the other answer... Mine did not return a correct string according to your last requirement.

Comment: As always, thanks for all your help 