# Combine unique values from ranges (with condition) into another ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I need to combine unique values from ranges (with condition) into another ranges on the same rows.
Actually, I post a similar question two days ago [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73163506/how-to-extract-the-unique-values-from-a-separate-ranges-and-concatenate-to-the-a) and the provided answer works as I formulated that mentioned question.
**But later**, I faced a new issues and I preferred to ask a new one to make it more clear :
**(1)** if all cells on a separate range e.g `[C7:C8]`  have empty value, 
then I got on that line `mtch = Application.Match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0)`

> Run-time error '13':Type mismatch

I can use `On Error Resume Next` before that line ,but I think it’s not the proper way to handle that error.
**(2)** if some cells or all on a separate range e.g `[B9:B10]`  have empty value, 
then I got blank lines (on top the combined values) at the final result.
**This is** a [link](https://easyupload.io/0ybd42) for the provided example with the expected output.
In advance, great thanks for your learning support and help.

[image]

```
Sub CombineRangesOneColumn_v2()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'_________________________________________

   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrDict, dict As Object
   Dim arrDB, arrDC, mtch, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value2
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))   'Place the strings from columns "B" and "C"
        Else
            arrDict = dict(arr(i, 1))                         'extract the array from dict items (it cnnot be modified inside the item)
            arrDict(0) = arrDict(0) & "|" & arr(i, 2)         'place in the array first element the strings collected from B:B
            arrDC = Split(arrDict(1), vbLf)                   'try splitting the second array element (string(s) from C:C)
            If UBound(arrDC) = 0 Then                         'if only one element:
                If arrDC(0) <> arr(i, 3) Then
                   arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & IIf(arr(i, 3) = "", "", vbLf & arr(i, 3)) 'add to it the value from C:C, separated by vbLf
                End If
            Else
                mtch = Application.Match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0) 'check unicity of the string from C:C
                If IsError(mtch) Then                         'only if not existing:
                    arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & IIf(arr(i, 3) = "", "", vbLf & arr(i, 3))  'add it to the string to be used in the next step
                End If
            End If
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrDict                         'put back the array in the dictionary item
        End If
   Next i

   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1): k = 1              'redim the final array and initialize k (used to fill the array)
   For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1                                'iterate between the dictionary keys/items:
        arrDict = dict.Items()(i)                             'place the item array in an array
        arrDB = Split(arrDict(0), "|")                        'obtain an array of B:B strins from the item first array element
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrDB)                            'how many unique keys exists 'place the dictionry key per each iteration
                arrFin(k, 1) = arrDB(j) & vbLf & arrDict(1)   'build the string of the second column
                k = k + 1
        Next j
   Next i
   'Drop the processed result near the existing range (for easy visual comparison):
   sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
'_______________________________________________
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Combine Unique Values

```vb
Sub Extract_unique_values_and_combine_in_adjacent_cells()
    
    ' The delimiter between the 2nd column value and the 3rd column values.
    Const dDelimiter As String = vbLf ' use e.g. 'vbLf & vbLf' to understand
    ' The delimiter between the 3rd column values.
    Const vDelimiter As String = vbLf ' use e.g. ',' to understand
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the table range (has headers).
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Calculate the number of data rows ('rCount')(exclude header row).
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = strg.Rows.Count - 1
    
    ' Reference the source data range ('srg') (no headers).
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = strg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to a 2D one-based array,
    ' the source array ('sData').
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Reference a newly created dictionary object ('dict').
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive i.e. 'a = A'
    
    ' The dictionary's 'keys' will hold the unique values from the 1st column,
    ' while each associated dictionary's 'item' will hold another dictionary
    ' whose 'keys' will hold the unique values from the 3rd column.
    
    Dim Key1 As Variant
    Dim Key3 As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the source array...
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Write the current value from the 1st column to a variable ('Key1')...
        Key1 = sData(r, 1)
        ' ... and check if it isn't already a 'key' of the dictionary.
        If Not dict.Exists(Key1) Then ' not a 'key' in dictionary
            ' Add the value as the 'key' and assign a newly created dictionary
            ' to the associated item ('dict(Key1)').
            Set dict(Key1) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dict(Key1).CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
        'Else ' is a 'key' of the dictionary; do nothing
        End If
        ' Write the current value from the 3rd column to a variable ('Key3')...
        Key3 = sData(r, 3)
        If Not IsError(Key3) Then ' exclude errors
            If Len(CStr(Key3)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                ' ... and add it to the 'keys' of the current 'item dictionary'.
                dict(Key1)(Key3) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
            
    ' Write the length of the 3rd column delimiter to a variable ('vLen')
    ' (to not calculate it over and over since it will be used in a loop).
    Dim vLen As Long: vLen = Len(vDelimiter)
    
    ' Concatenate the dictionary item dictionaries' keys to strings
    ' and replace the item dictionaries with those strings.
    
    Dim String3 As String
            
    ' Loop through the keys of the dictionary (dict.Keys)...
    For Each Key1 In dict.Keys
        ' Loop through the keys of the item dictionary ('dict(Key1).Keys')...
        For Each Key3 In dict(Key1).Keys
            ' ... and concatenate the values into a string ('String3').
            String3 = String3 & Key3 & vDelimiter
        Next Key3
        If Len(String3) > 0 Then ' the item dictionary was not empty
            ' Remove the redundant right most delimiter.
            String3 = Left(String3, Len(String3) - vLen)
        'Else ' the item dictionary was empty; do nothing
        End If
        ' Replace the item dictionary with the string.
        dict(Key1) = String3
        ' Reset the string variable.
        String3 = vbNullString
    Next Key1
            
    ' Define the the destination array ('dData'),
    ' a 2D one-based one-column string array with the same number of rows
    ' as the number of rows of the source array, .
    Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
            
    Dim String2 As String
            
    ' Loop through the rows of the source array...
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Write the 2nd column value, converted to a string, to a variable.
        String2 = CStr(sData(r, 2))
        ' Write the dictionary item associated to the key
        ' for the 1st column value to a variable.
        String3 = dict(sData(r, 1))
        If Len(String2) = 0 Then ' the 2nd column value is blank
            If Len(String3) > 0 Then ' the current string is not an empty string
                ' Write just the 3rd column (concatenated) strings.
                dData(r, 1) = String3
            'Else ' the current string is an empty string; do nothing
                ' Note that each element of the destination array is initially
                ' an empty string since it was declared 'As String'.
            End If
        Else ' the 2nd column value is not blank
            If Len(String3) > 0 Then ' the current string is not an empty string
                ' Concatenate the 2nd and 3rd column strings.
                dData(r, 1) = String2 & dDelimiter & String3
            Else ' the current string is an empty string
                ' Write just the 2nd column string.
                dData(r, 1) = String2
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the 2nd column
    ' of the source data range (no headers).
    srg.Columns(2).Value = dData
    
    ' Clear the 3rd column of the source table range (has headers).
    strg.Columns(3).Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: @Leedo: Sorry, had no time for comments. Will add them in a couple of days and possibly improve the code.

Comment: It Works great and fast 

Comment: Kindly could you review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278548/fastest-function-to-remove-duplicate-lines-per-each-cell

Comment: At first glance, it looks ok. If you could send the file to my email, I would take a look and try to pinpoint the bottleneck. But let me know that you have sent it because I don't check my mail that often.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next version. It should do what (I understood) you need:

```
Sub CombineRangesOneColumnEmptyRemoved()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrDict, dict As Object
   Dim arrDB, arrDC, mtch, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value2
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))   'place the strings from columns B and C
        Else
            arrDict = dict(arr(i, 1))                         'extract the array from dict items (it cnnot be modified inside the item)
            arrDict(0) = arrDict(0) & "|" & arr(i, 2)         'place in the array first element the strings collected from B:B
            arrDC = Split(arrDict(1), vbLf)                   'try splitting the second array element (string(s) from C:C)
            If UBound(arrDC) = 0 Then                         'if only one element(for second occurrence):
                    If arrDict(1) <> arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 3) <> "" Then 'not add it to the string if empty or already existing
                        arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & vbLf & arr(i, 3)
                    End If
                   dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrDict
            ElseIf UBound(arrDC) = -1 Then                      'nothing (arrDict(1) is empty)
                  dict(arr(i, 1)) = Array(arrDict(0), arr(i, 3)) 'place the string of the third column (even empty...)
            Else
                    mtch = Application.match(arr(i, 3), arrDC, 0) 'check unicity of the string from C:C
                    If IsError(mtch) Then                                          'only if not existing:
                        arrDict(1) = arrDict(1) & IIf(arr(i, 3) = "", "", vbLf & arr(i, 3))       'add it to the string to be used in the next step
                    End If
                    dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrDict                                        'put back the changed array in the dictionary item
            End If
        End If
   Next i

   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1): k = 1                  'redim the final array and initialize k (used to fill the array)
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1                                    'iterate between the dictionary keys/items:
        arrDict = dict.Items()(i)                                 'place the item array in an array
        arrDB = Split(arrDict(0), "|")                           'obtain an array of B:B strins from the item first array element
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrDB)   'how many unique keys exists!
                arrFin(k, 1) = arrDB(j) & IIf(arrDict(1) = "", "", vbLf & arrDict(1)) 'build the string of the second column
                k = k + 1
        Next j
   Next i
   'drop the processed result near the existing range:
   sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

If after testing it, nothing inconvenient appears, you may `ReDim` `arrFin` to have two columns, the code will load it without any code modification, but its content will be dropped in "B2" resized for two columns (`Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2)`). In this way, D:D will be errased in the same step.

Comment: All works great  except one thing , there are a blank lines on some cells `[D7:D10]`,
**This time** I clearly stated this issue on my question.
Sure I can loop **arrFin** later to remove that blank lines using `arrFin (i, 1) = Replace(arrFin (i, 1), Chr(10), "")`

Comment: @Leedo Yes, you certainly did it... I copied an intermediar version. I played a little with the last part and save different version to not loose time if something goes wrong. I will correct it immediately. Did it...

Comment: After thoroughly test (with the sample file and my real workbook), I am afraid to tell you that there are some issues.
**(1)-** There is still leading blank lines on some cells , kindly see the result of `Range(“D9:D10”)`.
**(2)-**  some cells are **combined wrongly** if the source cells is empty, to reproduce this issue, clear values from Range(“B2:C2”) and run your code.
**(3)-**  There is a bottleneck in your code (no offence at all) , because I tried on 27K rows and it took 11.8 second to finish, while the other answer (VBasic2008) just took 1.4 second.

Comment: @Leedo Since all my code has been designed on your confirmation that on B:B column will not be blanc cells and they will be unique. This fact was the core of the splitting. **It is written now** about these gaps but I did not observe that mention. So, please mark as accepted the other answer. I will not adapt it, even it is not so complicated.  I cannot keep the step with what you imagined in the meantime. As I always said, a question should be clear and containing all the necessary conditions. Otherwise, the initial logic of code designing may lead to such things, when new requirements appear

Answer (score 2):

Just for alternatives sake:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,B2,UNIQUE(FILTER(C$2:C$10,A$2:A$10=A2)))
```

Or, if available, spill all results in a single go:

```
=BYROW(A2:B10,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,INDEX(x,2),UNIQUE(FILTER(C$2:C$10,A$2:A$10=INDEX(x,1))))))
```